# Breakthroughs in quantum computing using non-standard quanta

Tags: experimental-realization, anyons, technologies

It seems that quantum computers can be classified by the [type of quantum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum) they operate on. Not entirely sure what category most common current systems fall into (eg. D-Wave, Google, IBM, Microsoft).  Photonic computing seems to be one of the more 'popular' alternative methods. Curious about other forms of [unconventional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unconventional_computing) quantum computing.

[Quasi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasiparticle#Examples_of_quasiparticles_and_collective_excitations) interested in a few [different cases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_quasiparticles):

- Phonon - sound based
- Roton - vortex based
- Dropleton - quantum droplet[*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dropleton)
- Fracton - fractal analog of phonons[*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fracton)
- Plasmon - plasma based

Also curious about [chronons](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/2690/chrononic-computing-quantum-computing-w-chronons) & [virtual particles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_particle).

**Have significant breakthroughs in quantum computing been made using non-standard quanta?**

Comment: What makes a "quantum" "non-standard"?

Comment: @NorbertSchuch "non-standard quantum" would be anything that isn't "standard quantum" (as stated in my question, I'm not sure what the "standard quantum" is)

Comment: @meowzz Aha, so "non-standard" is what isn't "standard".  That's not exactly a very enlightning definition.  In particular, once a significant breakthrough is made with a non-standard approach, doesn't this mean we have to consider it standard?

Comment: @NorbertSchuch Again, I'm not sure what the current standard is. Regarding standards in the future, this question may very well have significantly different answers.

Comment: But is "standard" sth. which has already been done in the lab?  Or where people are currently trying to set up an experiment? Or just sth. where people have made a theoretical proposal talking about how this could potentially be realized in the lab?  These are vastly different possibilities!

Comment: This also qualifies somewhat as non-mainstream, fwiw.

Comment: @heather updated

Comment: @meowzz if I'm not wrong, you just completely changed the question, and it is still really broad. Generally it's recommended you don't significantly change a question as to not invalidate existing answers.

Comment: As per @Heather's comment above, invalidating existing answers isn't a great idea. In this case, I suggest you read [this answer](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/1395/23), then, if you've got a more specific question, feel free to ask that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only two quasi-particle quanta for which I know there to be active research in quantum computing are phonons and anyons.

- **Phonons:** That state-of-the-art is given my answer here: [Phononic Quantum Computing](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/2588/phononic-quantum-computing/2608#2608)
- **Anyons:** Synthesizing the first anyonic qubit is still an outstanding goal, but major milestones have been discussed [very recently](https://journals.aps.org/prx/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevX.6.031016). This paper was the topic of an article with the very promising title "[Topological qubits arriving in 2018?](https://quantumfrontiers.com/2017/08/16/topological-qubits-arriving-in-2018/)"

Comment: If you could update your answer to reflect the updated question it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you count adiabatic quantum computing as fringe, but there was a [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1806.03295.pdf) using 4 NMR qubits to implement a adiabatic analogue to HHL which allowed them to invert an 8x8 operator with 98.4% fidelity which got put on arXiv a couple weeks ago. I thought that was pretty neat.

Comment: I had considered adiabatic & topological as well but did not include them (primarily because I do not the quantum they operate upon).

Comment: Adiabatic is a model of quantum computation. Any quantum that standard quantum computing uses, adiabatic can use too. Topological uses anyons.

Comment: NMR has been the very first scheme to experimentally realize quantum computing.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch True. My answer was referring to the pre-edit version of the question that used the phrasing of "Fringe" instead of non-standard quanta. The qubits are certainly somewhat common (albeit less worked on than other models from what I can see) but the methods were what I found interesting!

Comment: Question has been updated if you would like to update your answer.